# Vuex photoURL and displayName have been passed null to SetUser

Tags: firebase, vue.js, promise, vuex

My setUser

```
setUser(state, payload) {
   state.user = {...payload}
}
```

my payload in setUser for random data is

> user ===
>   payload{"uid":"pQOQL9AqMHNsozDE2EFGbMfHZlt1","refreshToken":"AEu4IL3c4doh1ON1ywqNEIXPjijktxAyQsYusC5twuvM61bHK6PpLHENyqKRKGCvNPR5IxBRC7JLQhkjv1qqiVUPdatRVM2Q8VdBCnvxyKkBjOEt_kM6bHCiJI6cdESdmFWZf2B7EjG9MwUJ7l8ASOpdbQLLVs9NtuW94dpNg1dkQShtUXB-sVCafvgtSnluGyZSWGhkt8uJ","**photoURL**":**null**,"**displayName**":**null**,"email":"yyy@test.com"}

My signUserUp

```
signUserUp(context, payload) {
  //name , email , and password are in payload
  context.commit("setLoading", true);
  context.commit("clearError");

  context.commit("setUserAvatar")

  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
    .then((data) => {
      data.user.updateProfile({
        displayName: payload.name ,
        photoURL: 'https://avataaars.io/?avatarStyle=Circle&topType=ShortHairDreads01&accessoriesType=Prescription01&hairColor=BlondeGolden&facialHairType=BeardMedium&facialHairColor=BrownDark&clotheType=Hoodie&clotheColor=Gray01&eyeType=Squint&eyebrowType=AngryNatural&mouthType=Sad&skinColor=Light'
     })
     return data
    })
    .then((data) => {
      context.commit("setLoading", false);

    db.collection("profilesInfo")
        .add({
          id: data.user.uid,
          registeredMeetups: []
        })
        .then(function() {
          context.commit("setProfilesInfo", 
             {    
                id: data.user.uid,
                registeredMeetups: []
              }
              )
          console.log("Document successfully written!");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
      });
      context.commit("setUser", {
        name: payload.name ,
        id: data.user.uid,
        photoURL: 'https://avataaars.io/?avatarStyle=Circle&topType=ShortHairDreads01&accessoriesType=Prescription01&hairColor=BlondeGolden&facialHairType=BeardMedium&facialHairColor=BrownDark&clotheType=Hoodie&clotheColor=Gray01&eyeType=Squint&eyebrowType=AngryNatural&mouthType=Sad&skinColor=Light',
        email: data.user.email
      })
      router.push("/");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      context.commit("setLoading", false);
      context.commit("setError", error);
    });


},
```

In signUserUp

an user will be created and upon creation value of photoURL and  displayName get updated by updateProfile
and after that db is connected again in order to create profilesinfo related to the user which is about showing what meetup groups the user is registered already

It works when in my setUser, I set the value of payload inside setUser and photoURL and displayName will be populated right and I can use it in my profile vue component

I debugged everything inside the console and I cannot understand why this part does not pass photoURL and displayName right

```
   context.commit("setUser", {
            name: payload.name ,
            id: data.user.uid,
            photoURL: 'https://avataaars.io/?avatarStyle=Circle&topType=ShortHairDreads01&accessoriesType=Prescription01&hairColor=BlondeGolden&facialHairType=BeardMedium&facialHairColor=BrownDark&clotheType=Hoodie&clotheColor=Gray01&eyeType=Squint&eyebrowType=AngryNatural&mouthType=Sad&skinColor=Light',
            email: data.user.email
          })
```

Note: I cleared my storage very often

or In second thought, can my issue is  because of using persistent data?

```
const vuexLocalStorage = new VuexPersist({
  key: 'devmeetup-it', // The key to store the state on in the storage provider.
  storage: window.localStorage, // or window.sessionStorage or localForage
  // Function that passes the state and returns the state with only the objects you want to store.

  //  reducer: state => ({
  //   keepLoadedMeetups : store.getters.loadedMeetups, 
  //   keepUser: store.getters.user,
  //   keepProfilesInfo: state.profilesInfo
  //   // getRidOfThisModule: state.getRidOfThisModule (No one likes it.)
  // })
  // Function that passes a mutation and lets you decide if it should update the state in localStorage.
  // filter: mutation => (true)
})
```

Note: after reloading and visiting other pages and come back to profile page, the photo is shown I guess the info became available then?

My `Profile.vue`

```
<template  >
<div>
  <v-card
    class="mx-auto"
    max-width="434"    
    tile
  >
   <v-img
      height="100%"
      src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/server-room.jpg"
    > 
      <v-row
        align="end"
        class="fill-height"
      >
        <v-col
          align-self="start"
          class="pa-0"
          cols="12"
        >
          <v-avatar
            class="profile"

            size="164"
            tile
          >
          <img :src="imgUrl" alt="">

          </v-avatar>
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="py-0">
          <v-list-item
            color="rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)"
            dark
          >
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title class="title">Name: {{owner_name}}</v-list-item-title>
              <v-list-item-subtitle>Email: {{user_info.email}}</v-list-item-subtitle>
              <template v-if="meetups.length> 0 ">
                <v-list-item-subtitle>Meetup organizer :</v-list-item-subtitle>
                  <v-card color="rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)">
                    <ol start="1" v-for="(meetup,i) in meetups" v-bind:key="i">
                        <span >{{i+1}}. {{meetup.title}}</span>
                    </ol>              
                </v-card>
              </template>
              <template>
                <div v-if="registeredMeetups.length> 0 ">
                  <v-list-item-subtitle>Meetup Registred :</v-list-item-subtitle>
                  <v-card color="rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)">
                    <ol start="1" v-for="(meetup,i) in registeredMeetups" v-bind:key="i">
                        <span >{{i+1}}. {{meetup.title}}</span>
                    </ol>              
                  </v-card>
                </div>
              </template>

            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>

        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-img>

  </v-card>
  <!--<h3>orginzer meetups:  {{this.meetups}}</h3>
  <h3>registered meetups: {{this.registeredMeetups}}</h3>
  <h3>All the meetups: {{this.$store.getters.loadedMeetups}} </h3> 
  <div style="word-wrap: break-word"> {{imgUrl}} </div>-->

  </div>
</template>
<script>
import {mapState} from 'vuex' 
export default {
    data(){
      return {
        imgUrl: this.$store.state.user.photoURL
      }
    },
    created(){
      // this.$store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
      //   if (mutation.type === "setUserAvatar") {
      //     //debugger; // eslint-disable-line no-debugger
      //     this.imgUrl = state.user.photoURL
      //   }
      // });
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState({
             owner_name: state => state.user.displayName,
             user_info: state => state.user
        }),
        registeredMeetups(){
          let rm= this.$store.getters.currentUserProfileInfo.registeredMeetups
          let allm = this.$store.getters.loadedMeetups
          let meetupsInfo = []
          let i , j 
          console.log("rm and all meetups are " + JSON.stringify(allm))
          for (i = 0; i < rm.length; i++) {
            console.log("rm=" + rm[i].toString()  )
            for ( j = 0 ; j < allm.length; j++){
              console.log("lm= " + JSON.stringify(allm[j]))
                if(allm[j].id == rm[i].toString()) 
                  meetupsInfo.push(allm[j])
                  }
          }
           console.log("meetupsInfo " + JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.photoURL))
          return meetupsInfo
        },
        meetups(){
           return this.$store.getters.loadedMeetups
                       .filter( meetup => meetup.creatorId === this.$store.getters.user.uid )
        },
        profilesInfo(){
          //  let currentUserProfile = this.$store.state.profilesInfo
          //                 .find( userProfile =>
          //                        userProfile.id === this.$store.getters.user.uid )
           return this.$store.getters.currentUserProfileInfo       
        }


    }
}
</script>
```

or **May be**, using then clause inside another the clause will have different effect ?
please take a look at my `signUserUp` then clauses.

my github repo 
github.com/KickButtowski80/devmeetup/tree/setting-avataaars

please if more info is needed let me know 
thank you

Comment: There's a lot going on in your question. Can you boil it down to a reproduction in Codesandbox?

Comment: github link  is helpful?

Comment: Yes, that's also helpful.

Comment: just shared my investigation with u

Comment: Shared how? Can you post the link in the question?

Comment: the link to github repo https://github.com/KickButtowski80/devmeetup/tree/setting-avataaars

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209198/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-tony19).

Answer (score 0):

I see there is some different parameter passed in `setUser()`

In your `signUserUp(context, payload)`:

```
...
context.commit("setUser", {
      name: payload.name ,
      id: data.user.uid,
      photoURL: 'https://avataaars.io/?avatarStyle=Circle&topType=ShortHairDreads01&accessoriesType=Prescription01&hairColor=BlondeGolden&facialHairType=BeardMedium&facialHairColor=BrownDark&clotheType=Hoodie&clotheColor=Gray01&eyeType=Squint&eyebrowType=AngryNatural&mouthType=Sad&skinColor=Light',
      email: data.user.email
    });
router.push("/");
...
```

You also said :

> It works when in my setUser, I set the value of payload inside setUser
>   and photoURL and displayName will be populated right and I can use it
>   in my profile vue component

Does it mean you put it in `/store/index.js` :

```
setUser(state, payload) {
  const {uid, refreshToken, photoURL, displayName, email} = payload;
  console.log('user === payload' + JSON.stringify(payload))
  console.log('payload detail info ' + payload.uid + " " + payload.refreshToken 
                           + " " + payload.photoURL + " " + payload.displayName + " " + payload.email )
  // payload = {
  //   displayName:"test7",
  //   email:"test7@test.com",
  //   photoURL:"https://avataaars.io/?avatarStyle=Circle&topType=ShortHairDreads01&accessoriesType=Prescription01&hairColor=BlondeGolden&facialHairType=BeardMedium&facialHairColor=BrownDark&clotheType=Hoodie&clotheColor=Gray01&eyeType=Squint&eyebrowType=AngryNatural&mouthType=Sad&skinColor=Light",
  //   refreshToken:"AEu4IL0tC9-fuEO-KZNwq953YDo2V7FBpjqB62FT6nXJ5d3r5u3Fzk1RYDzbjkO885rz0LrLyvIjHKHIDemiZsVPeio5XPXK5ntuRyFtLYcu-QOV4xnYYMn18mFxjo6P_TeqrnGIBuwpoto0ceTPxNfYFmedNyuxbNIU6MUVRp5WvnI7OWxVO5404RHIsnLrBsABoigDZgxs",
  //   uid:"XAhAqlBbs5VZCredSDqdWqKze6C3",
  // }
  state.user = {...{uid, refreshToken, photoURL, displayName, email}}
```

So, if you uncomment the line it works ?

Try to pass all the params used with the same key:

```
...
context.commit("setUser", { 
      uid: data.user.uid,  // id => uid,
      displayName: payload.name ,  // name=> displayName
      refreshToken: 'your-token',
      photoURL: 'https://avataaars.io/?avatarStyle=Circle&topType=ShortHairDreads01&accessoriesType=Prescription01&hairColor=BlondeGolden&facialHairType=BeardMedium&facialHairColor=BrownDark&clotheType=Hoodie&clotheColor=Gray01&eyeType=Squint&eyebrowType=AngryNatural&mouthType=Sad&skinColor=Light',
      email: data.user.email
    });
router.push("/");
...
```

Does it work ?

Comment: what do you mean same key? I tried it , but I still have the same issue.I have the git repo in comment area does it help? But the whole point is to have dynamic values which are passed to setUser can you explain your solution better?