# How to do overload to vue component decorator in typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I use vue with typescript decorators:

```js
import { Component, Prop, Vue, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  components: { .. },
  ...
}) ...
```

I want to add a property to pass to the decorator like this:

```js
@Component({
  components: { .. },
  myprop: ...
  ...
}) ...
```

But typescript doesn't know about my new property. (the javascript does), can I do overloading for @Component decorator?

Comment: I want to change the vueconstructoroption, but I don't know how. So every time I use @Component I put myprop and I don't want typescript say it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to do overload to vue component decorator in typescript?

You wrote that JavaScript already knows about your new property. As a result, all you need to do is to tell TypeScript that the property exists. Then the compiler will stop complaining.

You can tell TypeScript that the property exists by using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). Declaration merging tells TypeScript to combine the properties of two or more type declarations.

In the following example, we use [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) (a kind of declaration merging) to tell the compiler about the new property.

```
import { Component } from "vue-property-decorator";

// Augment the vue module
declare module "vue" {
  // Add myprop to the ComponentOptions type
  interface ComponentOptions<V> {
    myprop: string;
  }
}

@Component({
  data: {},
  myprop: ""
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {}
```

Voila! TypeScript no longer complains.

To keep the code more organized, module augmentation can go into its own file like this:

[image]

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you!

Comment: @Shaun Luttin can you plz check my post 2? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60572208/vuex-photourl-and-displayname-have-been-passed-null-to-setuser/60580838?noredirect=1#comment107183714_60580838